# React - Maintain form wrapper state on input change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a FormWrapper component that handles the state of some button/control elements (save/cancel/etc.)
The parent passes in the form elements, and the FormWrapper displays it along with some controls.

The problem is every time I change an input value, it resets the FormWrapper, resetting its internal state. In my case, it'll keep setting my isEditing value to false.

Is there any way around this, or this an anti pattern? I just changed over to functional components so hooks are newer to me.

Parent sudo code:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})

const onSubmit = () => {
  // Do something with formData in state
}

const handleChange = (change) => {
  // use setFormData to update state
}

<FormWrapper onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
    <input onChange={handleChange} />
    <input onChange={handleChange}/>
  </div>
</FormWrapper>
```

FormWrapper sudo code (has various css around the form I'm ignoring):

```
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)

const onStartEditing = () => {
   setIsEditing(true)
}

<div>
  <button onClick={onStartEditing}>Edit</button>
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      {props.children}
    </form>
  {isEditing && <button submit>Submit</button>}
</div>
```

Comment: Please make sure that your minimal example still reproduces the problem. You might not have included the bits of code that actually lead to the issue. Also working code that can be verified fast (e.g. in a sandbox) is to be preferred to make it easier for others to try your code.

Comment: I've created a sandbox and added the minimal bits necessary to make it runnable and it doesn't have the issue you describe: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dawn-gt6nq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Good advice, I shouldn't have been lazy about the question. I'm taking some more time to write up a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial issue, where `isEditing` is being reset to false every time you change the input value, is caused by you calling `setFormData` in your `handleChange`.  When you do this, your parent is getting rerendered.  This is the default behavior of `useState`.  When parent gets rerendered, your `handleChange` function is getting reinstantiated as well.  This causes a new `handleChange` instance to be passed into `FormWrapper`, thus causing `FormWrapper` to be rerendered as well.  Causing `isEditing` to be reset.

The simplest fix I see to solve this problem is to memoize `handleChange` so it doesn't get reinstantiated when parent gets rerendered.  You can do this with the `useCallback` hook, like so

```js
const handleChange = useCallback(() => {
  // Use setFormData to update state.
}, [setFormData])
```

Note that we include `setFormData` in the dependency list to follow good hook practice.  This is a safe move as well because `setFormData` will probably be a stable variable that doesn't change.

I think this would be a good enough solution if your form data is not too complex.  With only a few fields that aren't nested objects or lists.  Otherwise, I recommend using [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) to handle updating your form's state.  Note that `useState` variables are immutable.  So when you update their value with `setFormData`, you will have to create a new object.  Immer solves this by allowing you to do more mutation-y operations against a "draft" state.  This will ensure your `handleChange` logic is simple because you won't need to recreate your nested objects as they change.

Comment: Given OPs code re-rendering the `FormWrapper` wouldn't reset its state though.

Comment: The way OP's code is setup in the post, `FormWrapper` would indeed reset its state when it rerenders.  That's what `useState` does.

Comment: No, that's not correct. A component that simply re-renders (also with different props) doesn't reset/lose its state. The concept of component state would be pointless if that where true. Also see my sandbox with the code provided by OP.

Comment: You are correct.  I've learned something pretty fundamental about `useState` today.  Perhaps there is something else in OP's code not shown that is causing their problem.

Comment: Good information! But you are correct. I took the time to write up a short example in stack blitz and the code worked fine. I'm going back to my code to add in some of the more small complexities to see what might be really causing it. I thought it was simple state mismanagement since I was newer to it.

Comment: @trixn I was able to kind of reproduce weird stuff happening if you look on the method call WeirdInput here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qxgz57?file=src/App.js . After you click edit, typing in the first input or change the select works fine. But typing in that 'WeirdInput' makes it lose focus or something. In my real code there is a lot more parts, but it does have similar stuff to this.

Comment: @canpan14 That's because `WeirdInput` is a closure in the `App` component and it will be recreated every time `App` re-renders (which is when the state changes). React will think that this is a completely new component and will unmount the original one and mount a new one instead of re-rendering it. This is why it loses focus. The DOM node gets deleted and replaced with a different node. You should define `WeirdInput` outside of `App` so that it is a stable reference to always the same function and pass the handlers as props instead of using a closure.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll go attempt that on a large scale and see what kind of results I get.

Comment: @canpan14 Components should usually be independent functions in module scope unless you want to create some fancy HOCs. If you need them to call handlers or access state from the parent, pass that as props. Don't make them closures, it will not work as react doesn't know it's supposed to be the same functional component unless you memorize it.

Comment: I didn't know closures had that kind of issue. I pretty blindly just made a dozen closures in the same file that each handled a different part of the larger form. Which seemed to work fine back when I was doing class components, but obviously not now.

Comment: @canpan14 I don't think that this would have worked with class components either if you'd defined them in the `render()` method (which is effectively what you are doing now). Also there is no reason to define `WeirdInput` as a closure in the first place. You should simply use props. This is how it should look like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zmrgou?file=src/App.js

Comment: @canpan14 Also a closure is only a closure if it is wrapped by another function. Functional components shouldn't be closures. They should be module level functions. Class Components also shouldn't be enclosed in a function unless it's a HOC which still should not be called at runtime but at compile time.